# Term for the brain's automatic [psychological] response to being told to do something; to not want to do that thing anymore

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, psychology

I was wondering if there are any terms that describe a psychological response to this specific type of interaction- something along the lines of:

You know what academic work you have to do for a given day, have everything laid out and prepared, and are about to start when a [parent, sibling, significant other, etc.] comes up and tells you that you need to get the work done and that you should start soon; and suddenly you don't want to do it anymore.

When I was originally looking for an answer I found [a previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/469987/word-for-not-wanting-to-do-something-because-you-have-been-told-to-do-it) in the same vein, but none of the responses seemed to fit: recalcitrance, psychological resistance, psychological reactance, oppositional, and contrarian being the main ones.  The issue there is that, because of the way the question was worded-

> "What’s the psychological effect of when someone tells you to do something, and even if you were already planning on doing it and getting ready to, the second they tell you to, you just despise the idea of doing it."

-there is a base level of extremity above what I'm looking for.  A person's reaction to being in this sort of situation can manifest in a million different ways, but I'm trying to find terms for a reaction absent of excess emotion; where the primary impact on the individual is a subconscious undermining of motivation and desire to see the task through, both of which would have existed prior to the interaction (possibly coinciding with some of the terms mentioned in the linked question, but ultimately acting as an independent concept).

Comment: How can you be sure these parents, siblings, or significant others are real, and that you're not having paranoid hallucinations?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this depth of reaction may be considered an 'autonomic' response of the limbic or nervous system, in which deeper fears are triggered in relation to past experience of such commands. e.g. one's needs for autonomy, understanding, fun and acceptance etc.

Comment: Welcome, Art.  If you don't mind, may I ask that you please meditate upon [this guidance from Jon Ericson](https://tinyurl.com/y2c3k84x) and then consider expanding this into a proper answer? Jon’s post explains why we prefer answers with actual context and explanations, not mere copying of someone else’s words from some googled reference work without including any new content in your own words. Otherwise, we aren’t building up a library of expert answers by creating new content; we’re only showing off our own google-fu and adding nothing to our growing expert library.

Comment: I used to do this a lot, so as I corrected the habits over time, I developed a decent understanding of the psychology and (to a lesser degree) the neurology behind it.  At this point I'm just looking for a specific term for the specific reaction.  I imagine it would be something along the lines of a cognitive bias, but I've been unable to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

"Oppositional Defiance" is the correct term, but I think you just need to add a descriptor of the '**visceral'/'primal'/'knee-jerk'/'spontaneous**' nature of how the feeling immediately arises as an unbearable state.

That then puts the focus on the part you have emphasized and maybe then the suggestions on the other post will feel like a better fit?